# Notification in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification

Can I use All notification in single Windows Phone App (Tile , Toast and raw )? If yes then how ? Is there any example or link  which uses all these three notification?
I have checked these links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx

and also what is different between Toast and raw notification.?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you definitely can use all three types of push notifications. Why not? You just need to union the needed code from [toast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx), [tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx) and [raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202977(v=vs.105).aspx) notifications articles. The code is pretty much the same except a few strings. You can merge it in one and you will get the app that uses all 3 types.

The difference between Toast and Raw is that when app receives Toast message - it shows a 'toast' (Top-aligned popup with app icon and some text above the accent color). As for wp8 - toast only shows itself when app is not active (not pretty sure about wp8.1). You can also check whether toast came to your app from code and do some more actions. As for Raw message - you just can subscribe to receive it and make some actions manually in your code - show MessageBox, refresh some data and whatever. So it seems to me that Toast notification is improved version of Raw notification.